# The needs of photonic senseor for biomedical applications

Tags: photons, biophysics, sensor

I am doing a literature review on the topic mentioned in the title. When I write the review, I found myself a contradiction. Just want to listen to opinions from others :P

Nowadays, the development of photonic sensors for the use of biomedical applications is a hot research topic. The examples of photonic sensors include Mach-Zehnder Interferometer, directional coupler, ring resonator, etc. These optical devices can be integrated on silicon chips just like integrated circuit (IC). One of the applications is to measure blood glucose concentration. Some advantages of using photonic sensor for blood glucose concentration measurement are the high sensitivities and the ultra-low limit of detection (LOD).

However, is there the need for high sensitivities for the measurement of glucose concentration in blood. And, glucose concentration in blood would not be such "low" for "normal human". Is the ultra-low limit of detection (LOD) for the abovementioned application really needed?

Does anyone have good idea concerning how the photonic sensor could make good use for body fluid compositions monitoring?

Thanks!

Comment: Direct exposure to biological tissue "fouls" sensors (e.g. by depositing organic films on them). Diluting the solutions to the point where such films can either not form or can be easily removed is an important aspect of long term stable detection methods for medical samples.

Comment: Thanks CuriousOne! Do you mean that for some applications, the solution concentration has to be controlled to a very low level to prevent deposition of organic film. Could you give more details and paper about this?

Comment: I was merely giving you one reason of the top of my head why low concentration measurements would be a good thing for biosensors.

Comment: Obviously a non-intrusive method of measuring blood glucose levels is highly desirable. But the last time I checked a working device based on optical properties did not yet exist.

Comment: Thanks Urgje! Yes, the non-invasive method is really amazing. But, what is the working principle for that?